# Cannot append time extracted by datetime in correct format to an empty list

Tags: python, datetime

I have used datetime to grab the time from a string in my dataframe.

```
for i in DateTime:
    istring= str(i)
    try:
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(istring, '%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p').time()
        print(time)
    except Exception as Argument:
        pass
```

The results I get from this is the times in the correct format that I want.

```
03:12:34
03:20:59
03:29:30
03:38:01
03:46:32
03:55:02
04:03:32 ...
```

However when I append the times to a list instead of printing after each loop:

```
TimeList = []    
for i in DateTime:
        istring = str(i)
        try:
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(istring, '%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p').time()
            TimeList.append(time)
        except Exception as Argument:
            pass
    print(TimeList)
```

My list 'TimeList' becomes:

```
[datetime.time(3, 12, 34), datetime.time(3, 20, 59), datetime.time(3, 29, 30), ...
```

I want my list to contain the times that my code printed out in the first example.

I tried to change the type from  to  but that did nothing.

Comment: If you want to store just the string representation of your times you can do this: `TimeList.append(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))`.

Comment: The call to `print` gives you a string representation of the time object (return value of the object's `__str__` method). It doesn't change the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
time = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(istring, '%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S %p').time())
```

Adding the str() explicitly takes the string, as the time variable was originally an object, and was displayed as such in the list. This is why it appeared differently.